# Session issue on server

Tags: php, session

I have been uploaded my new site in live server. But when i open site ( on the initial stage ) session will generate. But if we click any sub link the site will goes to that page at this stage previously created session will expire. I need session value till the end of browser close. I think this will be server config issue Because this same site is working on my testing server.
Could you please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: we need the relevant code

Comment: `that page at this stage previously created session will expire.` may be you are calling session_destroy() in that file.

Comment: stat session on every page of your project

Answer (score 0):

check your session.gc_maxlifetime.  is this a server you configured or is it a shared host?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php